# What is difference between GeoJSON & Legacy coordinate pairs in terms of mongoDb?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, geojson, aggregation-framework, mongodb-indexes

I am trying to use $geoNear aggregation operator of mongoDb to calculate distances of users from current location in following way :

```
'$geoNear': {
   near: currentLocation,
   distanceField: 'distance',
   spherical: true,
}
```

With currentLocation being something like:

```
{ "type" : "Point", "coordinates" : [  -122.1575745,  37.4457966 ] }
```

My collection is of following type (using mongoose):

```
users = [{
  ....
  location : {                   // GeoJSON Point or I think it is ;)
            type: { 
                type: String
            },
            coordinates: []
        }
  ....
}]
```

I am using index (again mongoose's syntax):

```
userSchema.index({
  location: '2dsphere'
});
```

Now the PROBLEM I am facing is that, if I query using currentLocation as mentioned above (in form of GeoJSON) I get weird distances (very huge numbers), but if I use currentLocation.coordinates, i.e using legacy coordinate pairs ([-122.1575745,  37.4457966]), I get correct result. But [mongoDb docs for geoNear](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/geoNear/) clearly says that we can query using both *GeoJSON point or legacy coordinate pairs*.

I am curious to know what exactly is difference between GeoJSON point and legacy coordinate pairs ?

E.g Collection:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5277679914c6d8f00b000003"), "location" : { "type" : "Point", "coordinates" : [  106.6202887,  -6.1293536 ] } }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5277810148219d011c000003"), "location" : { "type" : "Point", "coordinates" : [  106.6202887,  -6.1293536 ] } }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5281c7ba2dfd7bdc64000003"), "location" : { "type" : "Point", "coordinates" : [  -86.9248483,  33.4480108 ] } }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5281c8b82dfd7bdc64000004"), "location" : { "type" : "Point", "coordinates" : [  -74.0087126,  40.7136487 ] } }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5281c9782dfd7bdc64000005"), "location" : { "type" : "Point", "coordinates" : [  -122.1575745,  37.4457966 ] } }
```

Incorrect result:

```
[{"location":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-122.1575745,37.4457966]},"dis":13.69288259318155},
 {"location":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-86.9248483,33.4480108]},"dis":12697164592.388557},
 {"location":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-74.0087126,40.7136487]},"dis":16328789117.58145},
 {"location":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[106.6202887,-6.1293536]},"dis":55446284682.14049},
 {"location":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[106.6202887,-6.1293536]},"dis":55446284682.14049}]
```

Answer (score 5):

Lets create some example documents and geospatial index:

```
> db.foo.insert({name: "Warsaw", location: {"type" : "Point", "coordinates" : [21.016667, 52.233333]}})
> db.foo.insert({name: "Stockholm", location: {"type" : "Point", "coordinates" : [18.068611, 59.329444]}})
> db.foo.ensureIndex({"location": "2dsphere"})
```

Distance between Warsaw PL and and Stockholm SE is somewhere about 810 km so let's check if it works as expected. First we can fetch document for Stockholm.

```
> Stockholm = db.foo.findOne({name: "Stockholm"})
```

Now we can run query using geoNear:

```
> db.runCommand({ geoNear: 'foo', near: Stockholm.location.coordinates,  spherical: true })
{
    "ns" : "test.foo",
    "results" : [
        {
            "dis" : 6.558558954334308e-10,
            "obj" : {
                "_id" : ObjectId("52876ab0b12c6fc62f5d9311"),
                "name" : "Stockholm",
                "location" : {
                    "type" : "Point",
                    "coordinates" : [
                        18.068611,
                        59.329444
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "dis" : 0.12715355275490586,
            "obj" : {
                "_id" : ObjectId("5287697eb12c6fc62f5d9310"),
                "name" : "Warsaw",
                "location" : {
                    "type" : "Point",
                    "coordinates" : [
                        21.016667,
                        52.233333
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "stats" : {
        "time" : 9,
        "nscanned" : 3,
        "avgDistance" : 0.06357677670538088,
        "maxDistance" : 0.12715355275490586
    },
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Distance between Stockholm ans Stockholm is close to `0` as expected. Distance between Stockholm and Warsaw is `0.12715355275490586`. When you run query using legacy coordinate pairs you get result in radians so we have to multiply this value by Earth radius:

```
> 0.12715355275490586 * 6371.0
810.0952846015052
```

So far so good. Lets check if we get similar result using geojson as a query.

```
> db.runCommand({ geoNear: 'foo', near: Stockholm.location,  spherical: true })
{
    "ns" : "test.foo",
    "results" : [
        {
            "dis" : 0.004183114486663965,
            "obj" : {
                "_id" : ObjectId("52876ab0b12c6fc62f5d9311"),
                "name" : "Stockholm",
                "location" : {
                    "type" : "Point",
                    "coordinates" : [
                        18.068611,
                        59.329444
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "dis" : 810998.0748260651,
            "obj" : {
                "_id" : ObjectId("5287697eb12c6fc62f5d9310"),
                "name" : "Warsaw",
                "location" : {
                    "type" : "Point",
                    "coordinates" : [
                        21.016667,
                        52.233333
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "stats" : {
        "time" : 4,
        "nscanned" : 3,
        "avgDistance" : 405499.0395045898,
        "maxDistance" : 810998.0748260651
    },
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Distance between Stockholm ans Stockholm is once again close to `0`. Distance between Stockholm and Warsaw is 810998.0748260651. When you run geoNear query using GeoJSON distances are calculated in meters. 810998.0748260651 is roughly equal to 810 km  so nothing strange here.

```
> 810998.0748260651 / 1000
810.9980748260651
```

Difference between both solutions could be smaller but it is just a FP arithmetics.

```
> Math.abs(810.0952846015052 - 810.9980748260651)
0.902790224559908
```

When you use `find` command with `$near` operator. When you create simple `2d` index on legacy coordinates pairs it can be queried using both `{$near: Stockholm.location.coordinates}` and  `{$near: {$geometry: Stockholm.location}`. If you have `2dsperhical` only `{$near: {$geometry: Stockholm.location}` will work.

Comment: as you told there is no impact on accuracy...but how does it impact in terms of efficiency..